# Converting a date with dot separators into another format without dots

Tags: php, date

From a JSON payload I get a date formatted like so: "2017.03.11". The desired result is: "11 MARCH 2017". I know how to remove the dots and convert the result into what I want using `date()`. But is there a more direct way to achieve it (without the step removing the dots)?

Comment: See [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: In first convet date to date object. Then convert it with needed formats

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y.m.d', '2017.03.11');
```

and then with the $date object you can do whatever you need.

Comment: Triggers a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

```
<?php
$date = "2017.03.11";
$date1 = str_replace(".", "-", $date);
$date1 = strtotime($date1);
$date2 = date('d F Y',$date1);
echo $date2;
?>

2017.03.11    input
11 March 2017 output
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but what I'm looking for is much simpler than that.